# Perl: "Modification of a read-only value" for one line script that used to work

Tags: perl, debugging

I am using this little line which is quite useful for parsing some data in HTML format, specifically for converting the HTML "special characters" into "real characters":

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities(-s);' <tmp1 >tmp2
```

It used to work just fine, however now it's telling me

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

Can you help me find out why? Am I missing a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you had `-s` there? Try replacing it with `$_`:

```
decode_entities($_)
```

`-s` returns a file size, see [-x](http://p3rl.org/-x)

> -s  File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).

While `$_` contains the line read from the input.

Comment: That appeared to be it, thanks! Not sure how it got turned into a -s...